# Turn a non-symmetric 3 dimensional list into a 2 dimensional list of lists in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a list that takes the shape

```
[[1,1],[2,2,2]],[[3,3],[4,4],[5,5,5]]
```

which when turned into a numpy array becomes

```
[[1 1],[2 2 2]],
[[3 3 3],[4 4],[5 5 5]]
```

so to be clear, i have a list made up of 2 lists and each of those lists are made up of lists

i want to put it in the form

```
[[1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5,5]]
```

or

```
[[1,1],
[2 2 2],
[3 3],
[4 4],
[5 5 5]]
```

flatten does not work because it just gives me a list of every component, but i want to keep the lists with the same components together so that i end up with a list of lists. The would be lists of different sizes as well so i don't think the reshape function works either.

The other problem is that in the example i gave the lists are made up of the same number, but in my actual code they are different numbers, so i can't simply tell it to put all of a certain number into each list.

I hope i am clear, if not, i will try and clarify

Comment: Although it can be done, using numpy with an array of type `object` (no- regular shape rows) loses most of numpy's purpose (speed, usabillity, aplicability of `ufuncs`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use two loops with [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), it works both for `lists` and `np.arrays`:

```
l = [[1,1],[2,2,2]],[[3,3],[4,4],[5,5,5]]
result = [i for sublist in l for i in sublist]
print(result)
[[1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5, 5]]
```

If you're not familiar with `list comprehension` you could use usual loops (equivalent for list comprehension solution):

```
newlist = []
for sublist in l:
    for i in sublist:
        newlist.append(i)

print(newlist)
[[1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5, 5]]
```

**EDIT**:

Or you could use `np.concatenate` or `np.hstack` as @Divakar suggested which are more readable but performance...:

```
In [225]: %timeit [i for sublist in l for i in sublist]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 885 ns per loop

In [227]: %timeit np.concatenate(l)
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.12 us per loop

In [226]: %timeit np.hstack(l)
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.3 us per loop
```

**EDIT2**

From @hpaulj comment you could use `itertools.chain(*l)` tp achieve with calling `list`:

```
import itertools
In [315]: list(itertools.chain(*l))
Out[315]: [[1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5, 5]]

In [317]: %timeit list(itertools.chain(*l))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 876 ns per loop
```

So the results are almost the same as for `list comprension`, may be a bit faster.

Comment: Thank you! I will accept your answer in a few minutes...can you tell me what that is called? i would like to look up more information about that. Thank you again!

Comment: How about `itertools.chain(*l)`?  That's a fast 1 level list flattener idiom.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use [`np.concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) -

```
np.concatenate(input_list)
```

Sample run -

```
In [19]: input_list = [[1,1],[2,2,2]],[[3,3],[4,4],[5,5,5]]

In [20]: np.concatenate(input_list)
Out[20]: array([[1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5, 5]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: @AntonProtopopov Well `np.hstack`, `np.vstack`, etc. all use `np.concatenate` under the hood, so I guess if `np.concatenate` works right away, so it's all good! :)

Comment: Yes, and also because `np.concatenate` are 3x times faster as from test performance for that case.